# How can I run my program when I already had the module and the error said: ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, torch, requirements-management

I am trying to run a demo.py from the github.
And the error I met is ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'torch'.
Then I install it by using the cmd: pip install torch and the cmd said that Requirement already satisfied: torch in C:\users...\site-packages(1.7.0).
My question is what could I do to run my program?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you did not download python with the right way

go to the `cmd` and write `py` and see if that works

Comment: I have already installed it. It runs the python file and then found the error so I don't think that is my problem. Tks bro